# Altbeacon library not able to find/trace transmitting beacon near device

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, eddystone

I am using altbeacon library for contact tracing. But i am not able to find/trace my device when it comes near my other scanning phone. I have two mobiles basically, one i am using for scanning and other as beacon transmitter. I am able to transmit as beacon from my phone number 2. I tested also in Locate Beacon app. It showed my phone in that. But when i am testing on my phone number 1, its not working. I am not able to see any beacon on any logs even though my `didDetermineStateForRegion` and `onBeaconServiceConnect` is being called.

Here is my application class below:

```
package com.example.mybeaconprojectaye

import android.app.*
import android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseCallback
import android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseSettings
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.RemoteException
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import org.altbeacon.beacon.*
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap
import java.util.*

class MyApplication : Application(), BootstrapNotifier, BeaconConsumer {


    val CHANNEL_ID = "myproximityservice"
    val CHANNEL_NAME = "My Proximity Service Channel"
    val backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = 6200L
    val backgroundScanPeriod = 3000L
    val TAG: String = "xoxo"
    val REGIONID = "rangeid"


    val uuidString: String= "id1"

    lateinit var beaconManager: BeaconManager
    private var regionBootstrap: RegionBootstrap? = null


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
        setupBeaconScanning()
        beaconManager.bind(this)
    }

    override fun onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        Log.e(TAG, "Service connected ")
        val rangeNotifier = RangeNotifier { beacons, region ->
            if (beacons.size > 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "found new beacons  " + beacons.size)
                for (beacon: Beacon in beacons){
                    Log.e(TAG,"New Beacon before condition check=${beacon.id2}-${beacon.id3}-${beacon.id1}")

                    GlobalScope.launch {

                        try {
                            val deviceUUID: String = beacon.id1.toString()
                            Log.e(TAG, "  before condition check=${deviceUUID}")
                                Log.e(
                                    TAG,
                                    "New Beacon=${beacon.id2}/${beacon.id3}/${beacon.id1}"
                                )
                              Log.e("xoxo","${beacon.id2}/${beacon.id3}/${beacon.id1} + "+ beacon.distance.toLong())


                                if (beacon.distance.toInt() < 2) {
                                    /*  val intentNotification = Intent(this@BeaconApp, HomeActivity::class.java)
                                  intentNotification.putExtra(Constants.DeviceConstants.IS_VIBRATOR, true)

                                  intentNotification.flags =
                                      Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

                                  startActivity(intentNotification)*/



                                    //sendSafetyNotification()



                            }
                        }catch (ex: Exception){

                            Log.e(TAG, "  EXCEPTION: "+ex.toString())

                        }

                    }
                }
                //  sendBroadcast(Intent(NEW_DEVICE_ACTION))
            }
        }
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(
                Region(
                    REGIONID,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
                )
            )
            beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier)
        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }

    override fun didDetermineStateForRegion(state: Int, p1: Region?) {

        Log.e("xoxo", "didDetermineStateForRegion state: "+state )

    }

    override fun didEnterRegion(p0: Region?) {

        Log.e("xoxo", "i just saw a beacon")


    }

    override fun didExitRegion(p0: Region?) {
    }


    fun setupBeaconScanning() {
        beaconManager.beaconParsers.clear()

        val altbeaconParser =
            BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25")
        altbeaconParser.setHardwareAssistManufacturerCodes(intArrayOf(0x0118))
        beaconManager.beaconParsers
            .add(altbeaconParser)

        val iBeaconParser =
            BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")
        iBeaconParser.setHardwareAssistManufacturerCodes(intArrayOf(0x004c))

        beaconManager.beaconParsers
            .add(iBeaconParser)
        beaconManager.beaconParsers
            .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.URI_BEACON_LAYOUT))
        beaconManager.beaconParsers
            .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT))
        beaconManager.beaconParsers
            .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT))
        beaconManager.beaconParsers
            .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT))


        /* beaconManager.beaconParsers
             .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"))
         beaconManager.beaconParsers
             .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"))
         beaconManager.beaconParsers
             .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15"))
         beaconManager.beaconParsers
             .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v"))
         beaconManager.beaconParsers
             .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"))
         beaconManager.beaconParsers
             .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"))
         beaconManager.beaconParsers
             .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"))


 */
        BeaconManager.setDebug(false)


        val builder = Notification.Builder(this)
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        builder.setContentTitle("Proximity Service Running")
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            channel.description = "Used for scanning near by device"
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
            ) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            builder.setChannelId(channel.id)
        }
        beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456)

        // For the above foreground scanning service to be useful, you need to disable
        // JobScheduler-based scans (used on Android 8+) and set a fast background scan
        // cycle that would otherwise be disallowed by the operating system.


        beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)
        beaconManager.backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = backgroundBetweenScanPeriod
        beaconManager.backgroundScanPeriod = backgroundScanPeriod

        Log.d(TAG, "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving")
        // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
        // wake up the app when a beacon is seentitle getting
        val region = Region(
            REGIONID,
            null, null, null
        )
        regionBootstrap = RegionBootstrap(this, region)
    }


    fun startAdvertising(listener: AdvertiseListener):Boolean {

        val result = BeaconTransmitter.checkTransmissionSupported(this)
        Log.e("xoxo", "BLE TRANSMITTER STATUS " +(result== BeaconTransmitter.SUPPORTED).toString())
        if (BeaconTransmitter.SUPPORTED != result)
            return false
        val beacon = Beacon.Builder()
            .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
            .setId2("1")
            .setId3("2")
            .setManufacturer(0x0118) // Radius Networks.  Change this for other beacon layouts
            .setTxPower(-59)
            .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(*arrayOf(0L))) // Remove this for beacon layouts without d: fields
            .build()


        // Change the layout below for other beacon types
        val beaconParser = BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25")
        val beaconTransmitter =
            BeaconTransmitter(applicationContext, beaconParser)
        beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, object : AdvertiseCallback() {
            override fun onStartFailure(errorCode: Int) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Advertisement start failed with code: $errorCode")
                listener.onAdvertiseStatus(false)
            }

            override fun onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect: AdvertiseSettings) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Advertisement start succeeded. uuid"+uuidString)
                listener.onAdvertiseStatus(true)

            }
        })
        return true
    }


    interface AdvertiseListener{
        fun onAdvertiseStatus(success:Boolean)
    }

}
```

and my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.mybeaconprojectaye

import android.Manifest
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconTransmitter

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        private const val PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1
        private const val PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION = 2
    }

    val TAG = "xoxo"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var result : Int = BeaconTransmitter.checkTransmissionSupported(this@MainActivity)

        Log.e("xoxo", "result: "+result)



        btn.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {

                requestPerms()


            }
        })

    }


    fun requestPerms() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        val builder =
                            AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        builder.setTitle("Location is off")
                        builder.setMessage("Please allow location permission.")
                        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                        builder.setOnDismissListener {
                            requestPermissions(
                                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION),
                                PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                            )
                        }
                        builder.show()
                    } else startAdvertiseBeacons()

                } else startAdvertiseBeacons()
            } else {
                requestPermissions(
                    arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                    ),
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION
                )
            }
        } else startAdvertiseBeacons()
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION -> {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "fine location permission granted")
                    requestPerms()
                } else {
                    val builder =
                        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited")
                    builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover devices.")
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                    builder.setOnDismissListener { }
                    builder.show()
                }
                return
            }
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION -> {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "background location permission granted")
                    requestPerms()
                } else {
                    val builder =
                        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited")
                    builder.setMessage("Since background location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover devices when in the background.")
                    builder.setPositiveButton(
                        android.R.string.ok,
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                            dialog.cancel()
                            requestPerms()
                        })
                    builder.setOnDismissListener {
                        requestPerms()
                    }
                    builder.show()
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startAdvertiseBeacons() {
        (application as MyApplication).startAdvertising(object : MyApplication.AdvertiseListener {
            override fun onAdvertiseStatus(success: Boolean) {

            }
        })
    }

}
```

And here are all the logs that are being printed:

```
2020-06-07 05:20:25.566 23822-23822/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2020-06-07 05:20:26.468 23822-23822/com.example.mybeaconprojectaye E/xoxo: result: 0
2020-06-07 05:20:26.810 23822-23822/com.example.mybeaconprojectaye E/xoxo: Service connected 
2020-06-07 05:20:26.848 23822-23822/com.example.mybeaconprojectaye E/xoxo: didDetermineStateForRegion state: 0
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong or if some step is missing. I tried looking into other answers on stackoverflow, but this is the only library where i am seeing new classes and interfaces everywhere in all answers. Too much confusion.

P.S.

I am trying to make contact tracing app. Any other library or something you can suggest will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing  phones 1 and 2 for your tests.  If you use BeaconScope to scan, can it see the transmissions of both phones 1&2?  If  you use BeaconScope to transmit, can your app on  either phone 1 or 2 see the beacon tranamission?

If you cannot detect beacon scope on one or both phones, check app permissions to confirm that location permission has been granted to your app. Go to Settings -> Applications -> Your App and check the granted permissions.

Also check that location is enabled globally on the phone and that Bluetooth is on.

Comment: i am able to see beacons transmitted on beacon scope from both the phones.

Comment: Ok, good. That confirms your scanning code is working, right?    Now check that you can see the beacon transmitted by your app on both phones using BeaconScope on the other phone.

Comment: Hey, the problem is my scanning code is not working. That is what i am saying. My both phones are able to transmit and i am able to see in beacon scope. But in my code i am not able to see/scan. Also the id1 has to be unique for every beacon right? does it have to be in that lengthy format only? or can be any string.

Comment: In your question you say the scanning code is working on one phone but not the other. yes?  But your comment above seems to contradict that.  Which is it?  Troubleshooting (especially remotely) requires being very precise about the details.

Comment: No no, i am sorry. What i meant is that now i am able to transmit, and also able to see it on Beacon Scope. Last night it was not working properly. But today when i changed my id1 for phone1 and phone2, its transmitting i guess, and able to see in Beacon scope. But the problem is in my code in logs i am not able to see. I want to scan it same like Beacon scope is able to do. Is it open-source? can i get to see the code? I hope you got my problem now. Can you please tell me if some step i am  missing in my scanning code?

Comment: I see no obvious scanning problems in the code, but you posted a lot of code -- so a problem may not be apparent.  You might want to change beaconManager.setDebug(true) and share a 10 second log excerpt after ojBraconServiceConnect  is called.

Comment: Hey @davidgyoung, thank you for all the support and answers. I am able to see the device after few seconds. The problem is if i keep the two devices near each other for sometime then in beacon arraylist of range notifier i keep getting the same device again and again with different distance metre value. How can i prevent it to not show one device more than once per day or something like that. Also i am accepting your above answer and upvoting it :)

Comment: Yes, the ranging API is is designed to give you a callback every ~1 second with a list of all devices detected.  A common way to maintain a list of only those you care about is by putting each detected beacon inside `HashSet<Beacon>`.  If the set size changes you know you detected a new one.

Comment: Understood. Thanks alot.